# Change a changeset

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

I don't understand how I can change the values of a given changeset.

### Setup

```
mix phoenix.new shop
cd shop
mix ecto.create
mix phoenix.gen.html Product products name price:integer
mix ecto.migrate
```

**web/router.ex**

```erlang
[...]
scope "/", Shop do
  pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

  get "/", PageController, :index
  resources "/products", ProductController
end
[...]
```

### The Problem

I start the IEX and create a new changeset:

```erlang
iex -S mix phoenix.server
iex(1)> alias Shop.Product
iex(2)> changeset = Product.changeset(%Product{price: 1})
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{},
 errors: [name: {"can't be blank", [validation: :required]}],
 data: #Shop.Product<>, valid?: false>
```

How can I change that given changeset now? The following code doesn't work:

```erlang
iex(3)> changeset = Product.changeset(changeset, %{name: "Orange"})
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{name: "Orange"},
 errors: [name: {"can't be blank", [validation: :required]}],
 data: #Shop.Product<>, valid?: false>
```

Because of the errors I can't do a `Shop.Repo.insert(changeset)` now.

I know that in this specific example I could change the iex(2) line to get the changeset I want. But I'd like to know how to manipulate a changeset after it's been created.

Comment: You could do `Product.changeset(changeset.data, %{name: "Orange"})` since you don't have any `changes` in the first changeset. If you had, you'll probably want to merge `changeset.changes` and the new changes map. Does that work for you?

Comment: I understand the `Product.changeset(changeset.data, %{name: "Orange"})` approach. But how can I do the second approach?

Comment: Try `Product.changeset(changeset.data, Map.merge(changeset.changes, %{name: "Orange"}))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Product.changeset(changeset.data, Map.merge(changeset.changes, %{name: "Orange"}))` does the trick. Thanks to [Dogbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320615/dogbert).

```erlang
$ iex -S mix phoenix.server
iex(1)> alias Shop.Product
Shop.Product
iex(2)> changeset = Product.changeset(%Product{price: 1})
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{},
 errors: [name: {"can't be blank", [validation: :required]}],
 data: #Shop.Product<>, valid?: false>
iex(3)> changeset = Product.changeset(changeset.data, Map.merge(changeset.changes, %{name: "Orange"}))
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{name: "Orange"}, errors: [],
 data: #Shop.Product<>, valid?: true>
iex(4)>
```

Comment: Then close the question.